# Sending information from windows phone 8 to Pc Window 7 windows forms

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to send information from my windows phone to the computer. I read some where that the usb cable is treated like a Ethernet cable. I created a server and a client(Phone is client) to try to send information. The program sends a message every time it presses enter.

Client Side

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    private bool Connected;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

        // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
        // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
        // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
        // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
        // this event is handled for you.
    }

    private DatagramSocket dataGramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    private DataWriter socketWriter;
    private bool messageSent;
    private static string port = "138";

    private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGramSocket.MessageReceived += dataGramSocket_MessageReceived;
        StartListener();
    }

    void dataGramSocket_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {

    }

    private async void StartListener()
    {


        string IpHostname = "127.0.0.1";

        var IpAdresses = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();


        for (int i = 0; i < IpAdresses.Count; i++)
        {
            if (IpAdresses[i].IPInformation != null)
            {
                if (IpAdresses[i].IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 6 && IpAdresses[i].DisplayName != null)
                {
                    IpHostname = IpAdresses[i].DisplayName;
                    break;
                }
                else if (IpAdresses[i].IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 71 && IpAdresses[i].DisplayName != null)
                {
                    IpHostname = IpAdresses[i].DisplayName;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }





        HostName host = new HostName(IpHostname);
        //EndpointPair endpoint = new EndpointPair(localHostName,)
        await dataGramSocket.BindServiceNameAsync(port);
        await dataGramSocket.ConnectAsync(host, port);
        socketWriter = new DataWriter(dataGramSocket.OutputStream);
        Connected = true;
    }


    private async void SendPacket()
    {
        await socketWriter.StoreAsync();
        messageSent = true;
    }

    private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            SendMessage(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }

    private void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        socketWriter.WriteString(message);
        SendPacket();
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }

}
```

}

Server Side

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static int port = 138;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var dataStream = new MemoryStream(1024);
            var udpClient = new UdpClient(port);
            while (true)
            {
                if (udpClient.Available > 0)
                {
                    udpClient.BeginReceive(ar =>
                    {
                        var clientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
                        var bytesReceived = udpClient.EndReceive(ar, ref clientEndPoint);
                        dataStream.Write(bytesReceived, 0, bytesReceived.Length);
                        if (bytesReceived.Length > 0)
                        {
                            UpdateUI(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived));
                            UpdateUI(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived));

                        }
                    }, null);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    private void UpdateUI(string message)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            this.textBox1.Text += message + Environment.NewLine;
        }));
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text);
        using (var udpClient = new UdpClient())
        {
            udpClient.Send(message, message.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, port));
        }
        textBox2.Clear();
    }
}
```

}

The information isn't connecting somewhere in the middle. On both sides nothing breaks. When I test the form by sending information to the loopback it works. I don't know why the information is not reaching the other side. Can you please tell me if I am doing this write and it is suppose to be done this way or can you tell me if this is not possible so I can stop working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a similar question and I answered there, [Communicate to PC over USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905253/communicate-to-pc-over-usb/26852461#26852461).

It requires editing the registry, the server code running on the device and I am not sure if the code will run outside of a development environment (I only need this to speed up my workflow and debugging - so its not an issue).

Comment: When I tried it out it says I need to convert the phone into a mass storage device. I have the Nokia Lumia 920 and 521 . I see no tutorials about this online. The the one I found the registry keys do not extis. Do you know how I can convert the phone into this?

Comment: You can ignore the "Setting up the phone" section, that is for OEMs which have kernel debugging on. I am using SDK for Windows Phone 8.1, the registry keys were already there and I could validate them by running "IpOverUsbEnum.exe", I didn't have to do anything on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

TCP/IP over USB worked OK in Windows Phone 7. In Windows Phone 8 however they removed the functionality.

Seek for other alternatives.

You could use TCP/IP over WiFi, or use BT, or write data to "Documents" and read with MTP COM API, or write data to isolated storage and read it using isetool.exe (this one only works for dev.unlocked devices).

Comment: Thanks , I wanted to know also why udp doesn't work over wifi? In part of my code I get the of the current wireless network I am attached to and send information. It still will not work. Ineed to use udp instead of tcp because I need to send information fast like stream audio and send text.

Comment: A1. Because you're sending them to 127.0.0.1 instead of the address of your PC? A2. Because your Windows Firewall blocks that traffic.
Also, if I were you I'd choose the port # above 1024 - ports below #1024 are usually used for well-known services.

Comment: With the part of the code that says ianainterfacetype I get the Ip of the wireless network if connected to one. I also only switched to a port under 1024 because I tried like 9 different types above it. Someone recommend that I try a "Safe port".